# Virtual Listview, threads and memory consumption that doesn't go down

Tags: multithreading, delphi, memory, virtual, tstringlist

*Update: Two people told me that it's hard to help me without the real/full code. You pretty much have it below, but in case I forgot anything, here it is! [laserrental.ca/MemoryProblem.zip](http://laserrental.ca/MemoryProblem.zip)

---

**Version of Delphi used: 2007**

Hello,

I am new to threads and virtual listviews, so my problem might be simple to solve; however, I've been stuck for a few days. Basically, here is what I have:

http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2012/32/1344440638-urlsloader.png

The user clicks on **Load URLs** and the URLs are stocked in the following record:

```
type TVirtualList=record
  Item:Integer; // Index
  SubItem1:String; // Status
  SubItem2:String; // URL
end;

...

var
 LURLs : Array of TVirtualList;
```

And the record is used to fill the Virtual Listview. Here is the OnData code:

```
procedure TForm1.ListViewData(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem);
begin
 Item.Caption := IntToStr(LURLs[Item.Index].Item);
 Item.SubItems.Add(LURLs[Item.Index].SubItem1);
 Item.SubItems.Add(LURLs[Item.Index].SubItem2);
end;
```

When the user clicks on **GO**, the app will launch one thread that will control the creation of worker threads. Each worker thread takes a URL, downloads it and parses it for getting further info.

Now, here is my problem: the memory consumption always gets higher and higher -- at least, according to the Task Manager. If I minimize the app and open it again, the memory consumption gets back to normal... but the virtual memory consumption stays super high. Now, I know many people say that the Task Manager is unreliable. Yet, after a while, the memory consumption gets so high that the URLs cannot be downloaded anymore. I get an **EOutOfMemory** error. My computer gets super slow.

According to FastMM4, there is no memory leak.

And here is the funny thing: if I clear the TVirtualList record, the memory consumption -- both the "normal" one and the virtual one -- gets back to normal. But unless I do that, it stays super high. Obviously, this is a problem since I want the app to be able to download thousands and thousands of URLs; but with this bug, I can't go too far.

**Code to clear TVirtualList record**

```
ListView.Items.BeginUpdate;
SetLength(LURLs,0);
ListView.Items.Count := Length(LURLs);
ListView.Clear;
ListView.Items.EndUpdate;
```

---

So I stripped down the app to the essential. There is no parsing and instead of downloading a file, the app loads a single local HMTL file with the use of critical sections. The memory consumption problem is still there.

---

**Control thread:**

```
unit Loader;

interface

uses Classes, SysUtils, Windows, Thread, Forms;

type
  TLoader = class(TThread)
  private
    { Private declarations }
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
    procedure UpdateButtons;
    procedure UpdateListView;
  public
    constructor Create;
  end;

implementation

uses Main;

constructor TLoader.Create;
begin
 inherited Create(False);
 FreeOnTerminate := True;
end;

procedure TLoader.UpdateButtons;
begin
 Form1.BSwitch(false); // Re-enable interface
end;

procedure TLoader.UpdateListView;
begin
 Form1.ListView.Items.Item[BarP].MakeVisible(false); // Scroll down the listview
 Application.ProcessMessages;
end;

procedure TLoader.Execute;
begin
 while (BarP < Length(LURLs)) and (not(Terminated)) do  // Is there any URL left?
 begin
  if (ThreadsR < StrToInt(Form1.Threads.Text)) then // Have we met the threads limit?
  begin
   Synchronize(UpdateListView);
   TThreadWorker.Create(LURLs[BarP].SubItem1, BarP);
   InterlockedIncrement(ThreadsR);
   Inc(BarP);
  end else Sleep(100);
 end;

 while (not(ThreadsR = 0)) do Sleep(100);

 Synchronize(UpdateButtons);
end;

end.
```

**Worker thread:**

```
unit Thread;

interface

uses Classes, SysUtils, Windows, Forms;

type
  TThreadWorker = class(TThread)
  private
    { Private declarations }
    Position : Integer;
    HtmlSourceCode : TStringList;
    StatusMessage, TURL : String;
    procedure UpdateStatus;
    procedure EndThread;
    procedure AssignVariables;
    procedure DownloadURL;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create(URL : String ; LNumber : Integer);
  end;

implementation

uses Main;

var CriticalSection: TRTLCriticalSection;

constructor TThreadWorker.Create(URL : String ; LNumber : Integer);
begin
 inherited Create(False);
 TURL := URL;
 Position := LNumber;
 FreeOnTerminate := True;
end;

procedure TThreadWorker.UpdateStatus;
begin
 LURLs[Position].SubItem1 := StatusMessage;
 Form1.ListView.UpdateItems(Position,Position);
end;

procedure TThreadWorker.EndThread;
begin
 StatusMessage := 'Success';
 Synchronize(UpdateStatus);
 InterlockedIncrement(NDone);

 // I free Synapse THTTPSend variable.

 HtmlSourceCode.Free;
 InterlockedDecrement(ThreadsR);
end;

procedure TThreadWorker.AssignVariables;
begin
 StatusMessage := 'Working...';
 Synchronize(UpdateStatus);

 // I initialize Synapse THTTPsend variable.

 HtmlSourceCode := TStringList.Create;
end;

procedure TThreadWorker.DownloadURL;
begin
 (* This is where I download the URL with Synapse. The result file is then loaded
 with HtmlSourceCode for further parsing. *)

 EnterCriticalSection(CriticalSection);
  HtmlSourceCode.LoadFromFile(ExtractFilePath(application.exename)+'testfile.html');
 LeaveCriticalSection(CriticalSection);

 Randomize;
 Sleep(1000+Random(1500)); // Only for simulation
end;

procedure TThreadWorker.Execute;
begin
 AssignVariables;
 DownloadURL;
 EndThread;
end;

initialization
  InitializeCriticalSection(CriticalSection);

finalization
  DeleteCriticalSection(CriticalSection);

end.
```

Comment: Sounds like you are running out of memory. Try not to allocate so much. Minimizing the app will trim the working set, but you can only reserve so much virtual memory. Where in the code above is the memory allocated?

Comment: I believe there is no code to allocate the memory.The thing is, the memory that is taken by HtmlSourceCode is only freed when I clear the TVirtualList, not when I call HtmlSourceCode.Free When I have URLs to download, the result is that at one point, I get an EOutofMemory error.

Comment: TStringList.Free works fine. You've clearly removed the code that allocates the dynamic array. How big is that when you run out of memory. You've also excised the html parsing. Does that consume memory. Hard to help without real code.

Comment: This is the real code. What you see right now causes the bug. When I run out of memory, I'm almost to 1 gig of memory consumption. I have about 1 gig of RAM.

Comment: If it was the real code then we'd be able to see `LURLs` being allocated. If it was the real code we'd see what you are doing with the Synapse code and the HTML parsing. So, I don't really think it's the real code. @Remy appears to agree with me, FWIW.

Comment: My point is, THAT code -- without Synapse and HTML stuff -- causes the bug. I didn't want to confuse people with useless Synapse and parsing code. It makes things longer to read and I really appreciate you guys helping me. Earlier, I said "I believe there is no code to allocate the memory." I could be wrong, but I don't believe there is any specific code. I put the full source code at the beginning if you want to take a look.

Comment: OK, it's good to cut it down to a minimal reproduction. I approve of that. But how do I run this? It's incomplete. `LURLs` is always `nil`. Presumably that's not the case in your version. Also, are you really creating 200 threads at one time? That's not very wise and could lead to serious trouble. Each thread will reserve its 1MB stack space. Each stack needs to be contiguous. Add a  bit of fragmentation into the mix and you'll be out of memory before you know it.

Comment: Ah! The ZIP! I didn't see that because it wasn't a hyperlink. Sorry. Anyway, I compiled and ran your project in XE2 with no difficulties at all. Memory consumption was nothing special. Did not rise at all. How long do I need to run it for? And what compiler are you using?

Comment: What is in the ZIP file is EXACTLY what I have. The URLs file is loaded with a TStringList. Then, I do a SetLength(LURLs, TStringList.Count). Then, each array of LURLs if filled by using the TStringList. To run it, you click on "Load URLs". You load the fake "filetoload.txt" and you click on "GO." I create 200 threads at one time, yes. I will try Remy's suggestion, of course. His system seems wiser.

Comment: @David Usually, one minute is enough for me. I have Windows XP and I use default Delphi's compiler that comes with Delphi 2007.

Comment: Yeah, creating and destroying threads like mad could be troublesome, but perhaps not. Anyway, I'd have a fixed pool of threads, to which I would feed work. If there was no work they would sit idle. When work arrives they'd pull it off and process it.

Comment: I've got 5 minutes and counting. No unusual behaviour. Memory stats constant. I'm on Win7 x64. I'll see what Delphi 6 makes of it.

Comment: @David Does the memory get cleared after you stop the app? Or do you need to clear the TVirtualList?

Comment: Clearing the list reduces the size of the working set. But then you'd expect that since it deallocates `LURLs` and also clears the list items list. I can't find a problem here. I'll give it a quick try on my XP VM.

Comment: Memory use seems to be growing steadily on XP.....

Comment: Memory grows on XP even if you remove the list view control. I'd suspect the model of creating and destroying threads the way you do.

Comment: Just thank you very much for your code sample, it helped me a lot :) Best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe sounds like either a memory leak or memory fragmentation.  Either way, it is hard to tell since you do not show how you are allocating and filling the URLs array itself.

I would suggest getting rid of `TLoader` completely and use a throttled queue instead.  When downloading a url, check if an idle `TWorker` already exists and if so then let it download the URL, otherwise start a new `TWorker` if you have not reached your limit yet, otherwise put the URL into a queue for later processing.  Each time a `TWorker` finishes, it can check the queue for a new URL to download, and if the queue is empty then that `TWorker` can be terminated.

Try something like this:

```
type
  TURLInfo = record 
    Index: Integer;
    Status: String;
    URL: String;
  end; 

...

private 
  LURLs: array of TURLInfo; 
  LURLQueue: TList;
  LWorkers : TList; 

...

uses
  ..., Worker;

const
  WM_REMOVE_WORKER := WM_USER + 100;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject); 
begin 
  LURLQueue := TList.Create;
  LWorkers := TList.Create; 
end; 

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject); 
begin 
  LURLQueue.Free;
  LWorkers.Free; 
end; 

procedure TForm1.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  StopWorkers;
end;

procedure TForm1.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
var
  Worker: TWorker;
begin
  if Message.Msg = WM_REMOVE_WORKER then
  begin
    Worker := TWorker(Message.LParam);
    if LWorkers.Remove(Worker) <> -1 then
    begin
      Worker.Stop;
      Worker.WaitFor;
      Worker.Free;
    end;
  end else
    inherited;
end;

procedure TForm1.ListViewData(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem); 
var
  Index: Integer;
begin 
  Index := Item.Index;
  Item.Caption := IntToStr(LURLs[Index].Index); 
  Item.SubItems.Add(LURLs[Index].Status); 
  Item.SubItems.Add(LURLs[Index].URL); 
end; 

procedure TForm1.ClearURLs;
begin 
  StopWorkers;
  ListView.Items.Count := 0; 
  SetLength(LURLs, 0); 
end;

procedure TForm1.DownloadURL(Number: Integer);
var
  I: Integer;
  Worker: TWorker;
begin
  for I := 0 to LWorkers.Count-1 do
  begin
    Worker := TWorker(LWorkers[I]);
    if Worker.Idle then
    begin
      if Worker.Queue(LURLs[Number].URL, Number) then
        Exit;
    end;
  end;
  if LWorkers.Count < StrToInt(Threads.Text) then
  begin
    Worker := TWorker.Create;
    try
      Worker.OnStatus := WorkerStatus;
      Workers.Add(Worker);
    except
      Worker.Free;
      raise;
    end;
    Worker.Resume;
    if Worker.Queue(LURLs[Number].URL, Number) then
      Exit;
  end;

  LURLQueue.Add(TObject(Number));

  LURLs[Number].Status := 'Queued'; 
  ListView.UpdateItems(Number, Number); 
end;

procedure TForm1.DownloadURLs;
var
  I: Integer;
begin 
  LURLQueue.Clear;
  for I := 0 to High(LURLs) do
    DownloadURL(I);
end; 

procedure TForm1.StopWorkers;
var
  I: Integer;
  Worker: Tworker;
begin
  LURLQueue.Clear;

  for I := 0 to LWorkers.Count-1 do
    TWorker(LWorkers[I]).Stop;

  for I := 0 to LWorkers.Count-1 do
  begin
    Worker := TWorker(LWorkers[I]);
    Worker.WaitFor;
    Worker.Free;
  end;

  LWorkers.Clear;
end;

procedure TForm1.WorkerStatus(Sender: TWorker; APosition: Integer; const Status: String; Done: Boolean);
var
  URL: String;
  Number: Integer;
begin
  LURLs[APosition].Status := Status; 
  ListView.UpdateItems(APosition, APosition); 

  if not Done then Exit;

  if LURLQueue.Count = 0 then
  begin
    Sender.Stop;
    PostMessage(Handle, WM_REMOVE_WORKER, 0, Sender);
    Exit;
  end;

  Number := Integer(LURLQueue[0]);

  if Sender.Queue(LURLs[Number].URL, Number) then
    LURLQueue.Delete(0);
end;
```

.

```
unit Worker; 

interface 

uses
  Classes, SysUtils, HttpSend; 

type 
  TWorker = class;
  TWorkerStatusEvent = procedure(Sender: TWorker; ANumber: Integer; const Status: String; Done: Boolean) of object;

  TWorker = class(TThread) 
  private 
    { Private declarations } 
    Http: THTTPsend;
    Signal: TEvent;
    Number : Integer; 
    HtmlSourceCode : TStringList; 
    StatusMessage, URL : String; 
    StatusDone : Boolean; 
    FOnStatus: TWorkerEvent;
    procedure UpdateStatus(const Status: String; Done: Boolean); 
    procedure DoUpdateStatus; 
    procedure DownloadURL; 
  protected 
    procedure Execute; override; 
    procedure DoTerminate; override; 
  public 
    Idle: Boolean;
    constructor Create; 
    destructor Destroy; override; 
    function Queue(AURL: String; ANumber: Integer): Boolean;
    procedure Stop;
    property OnStatus: TWorkerStatusEvent read FOnStatus write FOnStatus;
  end; 

implementation 

constructor TWorker.Create; 
begin 
  inherited Create(True); 
  Signal := TEvent.Create(nil, False, False, '');
  Http := THTTPsend.Create;
  HtmlSourceCode := TStringList.Create; 
end; 

constructor TWorker.Destroy; 
begin 
  Signal.Free;
  HtmlSourceCode.Free; 
  Http.Free;
  inherited Destroy; 
end; 

function TWorker.Queue(AURL: String; ANumber: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  if (not Terminated) and Idle then
  begin
    URL := AURL; 
    Number := ANumber;
    Signal.SetEvent;
    Result := True;
  end else
    Result := False;
end;

procedure TWorker.Stop;
begin
  Terminate;
  Signal.SetEvent;
end;

procedure TWorker.UpdateStatus(const Status: String; Done: Boolean); 
begin
  if Assigned(FOnStatus) then
  begin
    StatusMessage := Status;
    StatusDone := Done;
    Synchronize(DoUpdateStatus); 
  end;
end;

procedure TWorker.DoUpdateStatus; 
begin 
  if Assigned(FOnStatus) then
    FOnStatus(Self, Number, StatusMessage, StatusDone);
end; 

var
  HtmlFileName: String;

procedure TWorker.Execute; 
begin 
  Randomize; 
  while not Terminated do
  begin
    Idle := True;

    if Signal.WaitFor(Infinite) <> wrSignaled then Exit;
    if Terminated then Exit;

    Idle := False;
    try
      try
        UpdateStatus('Working...', False); 
        if Terminated then Exit;

        // initialize THTTPsend...
        // download URL...
        // parse HTML...
        //
        HtmlSourceCode.LoadFromFile(HtmlFileName); 
        Sleep(1000+Random(1500)); // Only for simulation 

        UpdateStatus('Success', True); 
      finally
        HtmlSourceCode.Clear; 
      end;
    except
      UpdateStatus('Error', True); 
    end;
  end;
end; 

procedure TWorker.DoTerminate;
begin
  Idle := False;
  Terminate;
  inherited;
end; 

initialization
  HtmlFileName := ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + 'testfile.html';

end.
```

Comment: I'll try to change the whole structure like you said. You have the full source at the beginning if that can help you.